# Array still following reference somehow even though I've passed another reference to it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've changed the array reference using spread operator but somehow the array containing old value is still changing according to the inital object.

**I have not been able to replicate the bug happening for the minimal example**. Seriously, I have absolutely no idea what's happening.

The only thing that makes it work in my real code is using the below instead of spread operator or whatever else there is to use to change references.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))
```

Other than that, absolutely nothing is working, even though using spread operator changes the reference.

I've put both an stackblitz and a snippet below (though they don't behave in the way my code does, they behave correctly, which my code doesn't).

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-array-reference-example",
  templateUrl: "./array-reference-example.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./array-reference-example.component.css"]
})
export class ArrayReferenceExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  initialArrayThatChanges = [1, 2, 3];

  initialArrayWithNoChanges: number[];

  dontExistInNew: number[];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initialArrayWithNoChanges = [...this.initialArrayThatChanges];
    this.initialArrayThatChanges = [1, 2, 4];
  }

  changesClicked() {
    this.dontExistInNew = this.initialArrayWithNoChanges.filter(
      v => !this.initialArrayThatChanges.some(a => a === v)
    );
    console.log(this.dontExistInNew);
  }
}
```

```html
<h4> Changed array </h4>
<p *ngFor="let arrayItem of initialArrayThatChanges">
  {{arrayItem}}
</p>
<div *ngIf="initialArrayWithNoChanges">
  <h4> Array with no changes </h4>
  <p *ngFor="let arrayItem of initialArrayWithNoChanges">
    {{arrayItem}}
  </p>
</div>

<button (click)="changesClicked()">show filtered</button>


<div *ngIf="dontExistInNew">
  <h4> Array with no changes </h4>
  <p *ngFor="let arrayItem of dontExistInNew">
    {{arrayItem}}
  </p>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-array-reference?file=src%2Fapp%2Farray-reference-example%2Farray-reference-example.component.html

Comment: If your example doesn't reproduce the error you should post your real code.

Comment: @ritaj's example is reproducing it and he and Shashank Vivek are probably nail on the head about what's causing the problem.

I'm going to add it to my post and try their solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have nested objects in your array? Rest operator only does a shallow copy of objects.

```
const original = [{a: 1}];
const copy = [...original];

copy[0].a = 5;

console.log(original[0].a); // 5
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5xrv3tkc/

Comment: That makes sense.

It's changing the array reference but not object reference, is this it?

Comment: Yes. It copies values of elements inside the array to another reference. But the values of elements inside the array are references to objects, so they still point to same objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went back to using JSON methods and it's working now.

Do you know if using JSON method is the best practice to deal with this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the spread operator is like Object.assign and does not deeply clone an object.

In case of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` , a complete new copy is created.

For nested objects, the spread operator might not help you much.

Comment: Hmm...so it's kind of changing the reference of the array itself but not the objects inside? Is that it?

In that case, would it be better to keep using JSON methods? Or is there a better way to work around this?

Comment: I would suggest you to go ahead with JSON thingy. I do the same in such cases. :(